# C# can't skip the next IF

Tags: c#

When "thursdaytime" = Closed <- i want it to skip the next IF
Can't get the "goto" to work.
Sometimes "thursdaytime" is 07:30-16:30 <-- and then the next IF is okay

```
if (today == DayOfWeek.Thursday && thursdaytime == "Closed") 
{
    sqlreadclosed(); 
    goto Ended;
}
if (today == DayOfWeek.Thursday && DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay > System.TimeSpan.Parse(thursdaytime.Substring(6, 5)) || DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay < System.TimeSpan.Parse(thursdaytime.Substring(0, 5)))
{
    sqlreadclosed();              
}
else
{
    sqlreadopen();                 
}
    Ended:
```

Can anyone help me out here.. im a Beginner at C# :)
If its helps, the point is, goto sqlreadclosed() if the clock is under 07:30 or over 16:30 and it works great. but when thursdaytime is "Closed" the under and over IF is crashing.. thats why i want to skip it ,if thursdaytime = Closed

Comment: why not use an else?

Comment: A) stop using GOTO. B) do some more tutorials. This is basic stuff and the fact that you state you are a beginner means you haven't tried hard enough.

Comment: GOTO's are very rarely a good approach.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to CodeReview (or you may just read more tutorials)

Comment: Try to simplify your 'ifs' and read a little bit about the 'else' statement

Comment: What is the value of `thursdaytime` when it "crashes"? What is the error message - there's probably an important clue in there.

Comment: CaMeX, does this code work, and you just want to [refactor the code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring), to make it prettier, and remove the `goto`? Or does this code not work? If it does not work could you give us the description of the problem that the program is showing to you?

Comment: Obligatory XKCD whor'n: http://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: @HansKesting: The value of thursdaytime is "Closed". The fix is to not try to parse thursdaytime as a date if he has already established it is the string "Closed". This is why he is asking how to skip that `if` statement entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess you wanted something like this:

```
if (today == DayOfWeek.Thursday && thursdaytime == "Closed") 
{
    sqlreadclosed(); 
    //goto Ended;
}
else if (
    today == DayOfWeek.Thursday 
    && (
        DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay > System.TimeSpan.Parse(thursdaytime.Substring(6, 5)) 
        || DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay < System.TimeSpan.Parse(thursdaytime.Substring(0, 5))
    )
)
{
    sqlreadclosed();              
}
else
{
    sqlreadopen();                 
}
//Ended:
```

Generally, using goto in C# is only necessary in very rare cases an it is considered bad practice as it leads to "spaghetti code" (i.e. code that has no clear flow). Therefore, use `else if` for your second condition.

Furthermore, I believe that you have a problem with your second condition, as the two time checks are mutually exclusive. Therefore, the condition will always evaluate to false. This can be fixed by using parantheses in the correct places. Generally be careful when mixing `&&` and `||` in the same statement.

Alternatively, you can reformat your code to reduce the complexity and avoid the two calls to `sqlreadclosed()` ([cudos to PJ_pavel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26273442/266919)):

```
if (today == DayOfWeek.Thursday) 
{
    if (
        thursdaytime == "Closed" 
        && (
            DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay > System.TimeSpan.Parse(thursdaytime.Substring(6, 5)) 
            || DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay < System.TimeSpan.Parse(thursdaytime.Substring(0, 5))
        )
    )
    {
        sqlreadclosed();              
    }
    else
    {
        sqlreadopen();                 
    }
    //Ended:
```

Comment: I think the best way to answer is to explain why  his code does not work and then give the OP the advice you want

Comment: You should definitely explain in words what changes you made and why, not just expect people to diff your code.

Comment: @Chris: Sometimes you just need time to wirte it up ... :-)

Comment: @AxelEckenberger: perhaps. My personal opinion though is if an answer isn't complete don't post it. :)

Comment: Oh it was confusion about IF ELSE and then "ELSE IF"

Comment: The statement is `if () {}` [`else if () { }`] [`else { }`] ([] indicating optional elements)

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case:

```
if (today == DayOfWeek.Thursday) {
   if(thursdaytime == "Closed" || (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay > System.TimeSpan.Parse(thursdaytime.Substring(6, 5)) || DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay < System.TimeSpan.Parse(thursdaytime.Substring(0, 5)))){
     sqlreadclosed(); 
   else{
     sqlreadopen(); 
   }
}
```

But as guys said in comments: try to read more about conditional statements usage and don't use GOTO -  it's a bad practice.

Comment: That is a nice tidying up of the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try using one boolean variable like 'skipflag'. And avoid using goto statements it is considered bad practice. Goto makes the code complex and harder to read.

```
     if (today == DayOfWeek.Thursday && thursdaytime == "Closed") 
          {
          sqlreadclosed(); 
          skipflag = false;
          }
     else{
          skipflag = true;
     }
 if(skipflag)
{
     if (today == DayOfWeek.Thursday && DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay > System.TimeSpan.Parse(thursdaytime.Substring(6, 5)) || DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay < System.TimeSpan.Parse(thursdaytime.Substring(0, 5)))
          {
          sqlreadclosed();              
          }
          Else
          {
          sqlreadopen();                 
          }
}
```

Comment: adding an extra variable in this situation seems more complicated than just using `else if`. flags are probably a good way to deal with getting rid of goto in more complicated situations but they make more confusing code here (especially with naming - I'd expect if skip flag was true that it would skip...)

Answer (score 0):

If it's "thursdaytime == "Closed"" but "today!=DayOfWeek.Thursday" then it skips the first if and goes to the second one which will raise an exception.So your first if should be either:

```
if (today == DayOfWeek.Thursday || thursdaytime == "Closed")
```

or:

```
if (thursdaytime == "Closed")
```

Comment: No, the problem is that it will go to the second if no matter what the result of the first if is. There is no `else if`, its just two independant if statements. This means this won't help the OP at all.

Comment: @Chris, A goto statement jumps to a label and it doesn't get back to where it was called like any other statement.So it does not matter what's after the goto statement once it jumps.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought about leaving the goto there. ;-) As it is going to the second when `today!=DayOfWeek.Thursday` will through short circuit logic evaluation evaluate the first part checking if it is thursday and then not process the rest. The goto, if it worked, would be fine but as the OP said it doesn't. And I'm not going to bother debugging that `goto` part personally since it is generally considered bad practice to use them anyway. :)